# Constructor ArrayAdapter onclick issue

Tags: android, listview

I need to display image and text in my listview when i click a button search but it giving me an error in my `setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, PNames,PImages));`.. I have two classes.
When I display onformLoad it working but, now I need to display it using a buttton, here my two classess :

```
    B_KZN.setOnClickListener(new View .OnClickListener() {

        @Override
            public void onClick(View Kv) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://10.0.2.2/php/p.php");

   try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("SKZN");

           for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                     

            JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);    
            String BookName = e.getString("P_City");
        PNames.add(BookName);
    String BookImg = e.getString("Pname");
        PImages.add(BookImg);
    }       
        }catch(JSONException e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }                   
        setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, PNames,PImages));
```

And my second Class,  :

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] myBookNamelist = null;
    private ArrayList<String> MyP = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> myPurl = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> Bname,ArrayList<String> BUrl) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_mobile, Bname);
        this.context = context;
        this.MyP = Bname;
        this.myPurl = BUrl;
    }
```

here my error : `The constructor MobileArrayAdapter(new View.OnClickListener(){}, ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>) is undefined`...**it showing me red line.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaring `this` as your `Context`. But you are in an Annoymous class of type `View.OnClickListener`

try this instead:

```
 setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(YourActivityName.this, PNames,PImages));
```

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of the constructor is of type `Context`, however when passing `this` to the constructor you are inside a subclass of `View.OnClickListener`.  As you are in an inner-class of your (most likely) activity, you just need to indicate that you want to pass the parent activity instance.

Where you're creating the adapter, use `MyActivity.this`:

```
setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(MyActivity.this, PNames,PImages));
```

Comment: way to take my answer and re-word it :p

Comment: @Blundell I beg your pardon?  I wrote this at the same time as you wrote yours, independently.  Unfortunately, SO doesn't show "seconds ago", only minutes.  You'd probably see that our two answers differ by about 5 seconds.  I don't like when others copy my answers and I don't do it myself.

Comment: It does show edit's too your answer, and I watched your original answer then your change. Don't worry yourself

Comment: @Blundell: yes, I changed it.  I often answer with the main point and then update with more information.  Is that a crime? :)   But I'll give you a +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your activity where you set adapter to your ListView, it will work

```
setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(yourActivityname.this, PNames,PImages));
```